# Swift: How to find Realm database contains custom string

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I had a problem to filter realm database. I search movie name and wrote values to realm database from Json. After written, I assign to tableview cell to show results. At the second search, I always get same values because of the getting all result from the database. I need to filter new values from the database and set to tableview. Please help me !

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.counter = 0
    aranacak_kelime = searchBar.text!
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + aranacak_kelime + "&apikey=c6e----")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil)
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else{
            if let content=data
            {
                    do
                    {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as AnyObject
                        if let search = json["Search"] as? [NSDictionary]
                        {
                            DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
                                             autoreleasepool {
                            let realm = try! Realm()
                 print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
                            for result in search
                            {
                               let movie = Movie()
                               movie.name = result["Title"] as! String
                               movie.type = result["Type"] as! String
                               movie.year = result["Year"] as! String
                               movie.poster = result["Poster"] as! String

                           try! realm.write {
                               realm.add(movie)
                           }
                           self.counter += 1
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}
                          }
                    }
           }
       }   
  }
  catch{
   print("error in JSONSerialization")
      }                   
 }
}}task.resume()}
```

and tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    let realm = try! Realm()

    //let results = realm.objects(Movie.self).filter("ANY name.contains('aranacak_kelime')")

    let results = realm.objects(Movie.self)
    cell.movieName.text = results[row].name
    cell.movieYear.text = results[row].year
    cell.movieType.text = results[row].type
    let imageUrl = results[row].poster
}
```

and my Movie class

```
class Movie: Object{
@objc dynamic var name:String = ""
@objc dynamic var type:String = ""
@objc dynamic var year:String = ""
@objc dynamic var poster:String = ""
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking and the code is a bit unclear; what is `search`? Why are you adding the same movie over and over in the database? Your question says *I search movie name* but there's nothing in the code that searches. As you asking how to query Realm for a movie name? If so, please include the code you've tried and also see [Filtering Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering). Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I used an Omdb API for getting movies. I write a movie name and search from the omdb api. I get the result to json. After json, I parse all result and write to realm. I add search code to my question.

Comment: This question is too vague, and what's being asked doesn't appear to be related to the code in the question. You're asking *How to find Realm database contains custom string* but there's nothing in the code that searches Realm and it's unclear what a custom string is. Maybe you mean a partial string search? Can you update and clarify your question and include relevant code? Then we can take a look and try to help. Please review the following guide: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have a couple of issues. If you search for the same movie twice, you will be saving the same result to your realm DB. So maybe use some sort of ID and when saving use `realm.add(movie, update: true)` this will prevent from storing the same movie twice.
The other issue is that you are not filtering the results you load on the tableview.

You should have an auxiliar method where you use the search bar text to filter your results before reloading your table view, something like:

`func reloadContent() {
self.data = realm.objects(Movie.self).filter("ANY name.contains(YOUR_SEARCHBAR.text)")
self.tableView.reloadData()
}`

You should change this line `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}` for `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.reloadContent()}`

and finally have a property of `var data: Results<Movie>?` where you will store the filtered movies. You will have to change your table view datasource delegate methods to use this data instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `realm.add(movie,update:true)` dont run because of the " 'Movie' does not have a primary key and can not be updated". `realm.objects(Movie.self).filter("ANY name.contains(aranacak_kelime) ")` dont run because of the 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY name.contains(aranacak_kelime) "'. Finally, `self.reloadContent()` method dont understand from Xcode because reloadContent() dont found which refer it

Comment: There are a number of coding errors in this answer. Really though, the OP question is so vague I am not sure this is the correct direction. The OP stated *search from the omdb api* so it looks like he's already doing a search elsewhere so having a filter here won't help. They also stated *contains custom string* and it's unclear what that means - possibly a partial string search? I think the OP needs to clarify the question before an answer is attempted. Just IMO.

Comment: @Jay No I think it is clear. My app only has search bar and table view. When you search some movie name,(after the search button clicked), I got movie details from the url and set to realm database. After the realm saving data, I set to cell for see data in the table.

Comment: @Kamil In my answer I said that you should add a PK if you don't want to have repeated values on your DB. I guess that omdb API already returns an ID on the movie json, so you could add it as a property to your Movie object and use it as PK. Update should work with that. About the other two comments, those are pseudo code, it might miss something, but I guess are good pointers of what you could do.
`self.reloadContent()` is a new func that you should add.
`realm.objects(Movie.self).filter("ANY name.contains(aranacak_kelime) ")` check realm docs to see how to perform a search.

Comment: @Kamil I think this would solve the filtering issue:
```let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", aranacak_kelime)
realm.objects(Movie.self).filter(predicate) ```

Comment: @Kamil The question is very vague and it's unclear what is being asked which is why this answerer is having a hard time providing a clear answer. Your comment above adds more confusion. **When you search some movie name...  got movie details from the url and set to realm database... I set to cell for see data in the table**. None of that has anything to do with searching *Realm* for a custom string. We want to help but need to have details and accurate information to craft a good answer - as it is, we are just guessing. Also, the question doesn't include any kind of searching. Please clarify!

Comment: @Lucho thank you very much it solved my all problems. :)

Comment: @Jay thank you for your supporting, I solved my problems with Lucho's comment.  I use NSPredicate and solved.

Comment: @Kamil glad it helped.